# Vuelidate Custom Validator

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I am trying to get the Vuelidate custom validator provided by the docs to work with my Vutify

This is the line of code from the docs

```
const mustBeCool = (value) => value.indexOf('cool') >= 0
```

When I add it to my validators like so it doesnt seem to work

```
name: { required, minLength: minLength(4), mustBeCool }
```

Here is the CodePen

https://codepen.io/jamiebrs/pen/OKjXev?editors=1010

What am I missing?

Comment: I dont think this is the problem with your code, in your `nameErrors` computed property you have `this.$v.name.maxLength` instead of `this.$v.name.minLength`, otherwise it's working fine for me.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, dumb oversight on my part thanks.